# Confusion about the first fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces

I am reading about the first fundamental form. The definition on Wolfram is:

> Let $M$ be a regular surface with $v_p, w_p$ points in the tangent space $M_p$ of $M$. Then, the *first fundamental form* is the inner product of tangent vectors: $I(v_p, w_p) = v_p \cdot w_p$.

So, if I understand correctly, the first fundamental form is actually a map $I: M_p \times M_p \to \mathbb{R}$. Is that correct?

Now, Wikipedia claims something similar.

> The *first fundamental form* is the inner product on the tangent space of a surface in three-dimensional Euclidean space which is induced canonically from the dot product of $\mathbb{R}^3: I(x,y) = \langle x, y \rangle$.

However, it then proceeds to say that the first fundamental form may be represented as a symmetric matrix: $$ I(x,y) = x^T \begin{bmatrix}  E & F \\ F & G   \end{bmatrix} y,$$ where $E, F, G$ are the coefficients of the first fundamental form.

This is super weird to me, because this second representation strikes me as different from the first one. However, I suspect that $x$ and $y$ in the second interpretation are not the same $x$ and $y$ as in the definition. However, I can't make much sense of what exactly they are and in what sense they are different.

I would appreciate it if someone clarified these things to me as  the confusion is driving me crazy.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are now your tangent vector, but represented with respect to the basis of the tangent space given by the derivatives of your parametrization. Stop trying to learn the subject from a mish-mash of web sources and read a textbook. You can download mine for free (link in my profile).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\brak}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$The first definition meshes with the second if we let the point $p$ of tangency range over $M$, and for each $p$ we let $v_{p}$ and $w_{p}$ range over all ordered pairs of tangent vectors to $M$ at $p$.

The functions in the wikipedia definition are not intrinsic to the geometry of $M$, but instead depend on a coordinate system $(s, t)$ for $M$. If $(\dd_{s}, \dd_{t})$ denotes the associated coordinate frame, the resulting *components of the first fundamental form* are defined by
\begin{align*}
  E(s, t) &= \brak{\dd_{s}, \dd_{s}}, \\
  F(s, t) &= \brak{\dd_{s}, \dd_{t}}, \\
  G(s, t) &= \brak{\dd_{t}, \dd_{t}}.
\end{align*}
We may then let $x$ and $y$ denote ordinary vectors in Euclidean three-space that are tangent to $M$ at some point $p$, write each as a linear combination of the coordinate frame $(\dd_{s}, \dd_{t})$, and use the resulting *ordered pairs* to form Wikipedia's matrix product.

There are technical definitions, for which search terms include *tangent bundle*, *Riemannian metric*, and *tensor components*. Those are all well-explained elsewhere on-site.